# How to derive the dual of a conic programming problem, $\min_{x\in L}\{c^T x: \,\, Ax-b\in K\}$?

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, semidefinite-programming, conic-programming

I'm trying to get a better understanding of the derivation of the dual problem associated with a given *conic problem*.

From [these notes](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/%7Enemirovs/ICMNemirovski.pdf) (pdf alert), a conic problem is written (see page 5) as
$$\min_x  \{c^T x: \,\, Ax-b\in K\},\tag1$$
for some closed convex cone $K$.

To obtain the dual problem, the text then argues that, defining the Lagrangian as $L(x,\lambda)=c^T x -\lambda^T(Ax-b)$, we have must
$$\min_x L(x,\lambda)\le \min_x\{c^T x: \,\,Ax-b\in K\}, \quad \forall \lambda\in K^*,\tag2$$
where $K^*$ is the dual cone of $K$ (the text doesn't explicitly write these equations, but this is how I understand what is being said around pages 6 and 7). The dual problem should then come, I think, from
$$\max_\lambda\{ \min_x L(x,\lambda) : \,\, \lambda\in K^*\}
= \max_\lambda\{ \min_x [(c-A^T\lambda)^Tx+ b^T\lambda] : \,\, \lambda\in K^*\}.\tag3$$
The dual problem is written, in the notes, as
$$\max_\lambda\{b^T\lambda: \,\, A^T\lambda=c, \,\, \lambda\in K^*\}.\tag4$$

The domain of $x$ is not actually explicitly specified here (or at least I'm not seeing it), but I'm assuming it's either $x\ge0$, or $x\in L$ for some other closed convex cone $L$.

How do we get from (3) to (4)? I can sort of see it when $x\ge0$, but I'm unsure how to operate in the more general case of $x\in L$.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Oops, didn't see that you had $x\in L$ in the question. I only answered for $L=\mathbb{R}^n$. Below, I give a Lagrangian approach for $L$ a closed, convex cone.

---

I will outline an approach of Lagrangian duality.
Given the primal problem and its value $\nu(P)$, i.e.,
\begin{array}{lcl}
\begin{align}
\nu(P):= & \min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} & c^\top x & \\
& \text{s.t.} & Ax-b\in K
\end{align}
\end{array}
we can write the Lagrangian
\begin{align}
L(x;\lambda):= c^\top x + \lambda^\top(b-Ax)
\end{align}
and observe that
\begin{align}
\nu(P) \overset{(i)}{=} \min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}\max_{\lambda\in K^*} L(x;\lambda) \overset{(ii)}{\geq} \max_{\lambda\in K^*}\min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} L(x;\lambda) \overset{(iii)}{=} \nu(D)
\end{align}
where $(i)$ follows since $K$ and $K^*$ are dual cones (moving the constraints into the Lagrangian), $(ii)$ follows from the max-min inequality, and $(iii)$ follows from defining the value of the dual problem to be
\begin{array}{lcl}
\begin{align}
\nu(D):= & \min_{\lambda\in\mathbb{R}^m} & b^\top \lambda & \\
& \text{s.t.} & A^\top \lambda = c\\
&&\lambda\in K^*
\end{align}
\end{array}
and rewriting/evaluating the Lagrangian to give a nontrivial lower bound
\begin{align}
L(x;\lambda)= b^\top\lambda + \langle  c-A^\top\lambda, x\rangle \implies \min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} L(x;\lambda) = \begin{cases} -\infty,\quad &\text{if $A^\top \lambda \neq c$};\\ b^\top\lambda,\quad &\text{if $A^\top \lambda=c$}.\end{cases}
\end{align}

So, the expressions for conic duals are very similar to LP duality, and the derivations are similar symbollically, but there are a few important differences, two of which are:

- In LP duality, exactly one of the following holds:

  - the primal is infeasible and dual is unbounded;
  - the dual is infeasible and primal is unbounded;
  - the dual is infeasible and primal is infeasible;
  - the dual is feasible and primal is feasible, and $(ii)$ is an EQUALITY (strong duality).
    That is, the optimal solutions are ATTAINED, so there actually exist feasible $x^*,\lambda^*$ that give $\nu(P)$ and $\nu(D)$ when plugged into the primal and dual objective functions, respectively.
- In conic duality, attainment of the solutions is not guaranteed without additional assumptions, UNLIKE linear programming. If we replaced $\max/\min$ with $\sup/\inf$, there are cases where both programs are feasible, and we could have strong duality of the *values* of the dual programs, but not necessarily *attainment*. In general, we need to be careful. For more, see [here](https://ideas.repec.org/p/ems/eureir/1554.html).

---

Consider the following problem where $L$ is a closed, convex cone
\begin{array}{lcl}
\begin{align}
\nu(P):= & \min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} & c^\top x & \\
& \text{s.t.} & Ax-b\in K\\
&& x\in L.
\end{align}
\end{array}
Then
\begin{align}
L(x;\lambda,\mu) &= \langle c,x \rangle + \langle \lambda,b-Ax \rangle + \langle \mu,-x \rangle\\
&= \langle b,\lambda \rangle + \langle c-A^\top\lambda-\mu,x \rangle
\end{align}
so
\begin{align}
\nu(P) = \min_{x\in L}\max_{\lambda\in K^*,\mu\in L^*} L(x;\lambda,\mu) \geq  \min_{x\in L}\max_{\lambda\in K^*,\mu\in L^*} L(x;\lambda,\mu) = \nu(D)
\end{align}
where
\begin{array}{lcl}
\begin{align}
\nu(D):= & \max_{\lambda,\mu} & b^\top \lambda & \\
& \text{s.t.} & c-A^\top\lambda-\mu\in L^*\\
&& \lambda\in K^*,\\
&& \mu\in L^*.
\end{align}
\end{array}

Comment: Please define L. Is it the whole space? is it  a subspace ? Is it another cone?

Comment: Thanks, just edited

Comment: It seems correct and I upvoted! But I will give it a try using again Fenchel's Duality scheme! Everything now will be more complicated!

Comment: I have made an edit including the case where$ L$ is a closed convex cone!

Answer (score 1):

We can make use of Fenchel's Duality scheme, defining:

$P(x)=c^{T}x$ and $Q(Ax)=0$ if $Ax\,\in\,K+b,\,\,$ $-\infty\,\,$ otherwise. So the function $Q(Ax)=-\delta_{K+b}(Ax)$ where $\delta$ is the indicator function, i.e. $\delta_{A}(x)=0$ if $x\in\,A$ and $+\infty$ otherwise.

We first calculate $P^{\star}(x^{\star})$=sup$ \left\{x^{\star}x-c^{T}x \right\}$ which is $0$ if $x^{\star}=c$, $+\infty$ otherwise.

Now the concave conjugate of $\delta_{K+b}\,\,$ is inf$\left\{x^{\star}x-(-\delta_{K+b}(Ax)) \right\}$ . This can be easily calculated using another Fenchel duality scheme

(defining a new variable $y$ and setting a constraint $y=Ax$) (see Rockafellar: Convex Analysis pages 332-335) and getting:

$ Q^{\star}=-\delta_{(K+b)^{\star}}(y^{\star})$ under

$A^{\star}y^{\star}=x^{\star}$ and since by $P^{\star}$ we have $x^{\star}=c$ and the dual problem is :

Maximize $-\delta_{(K+b)^{\star}}(y^{\star})$ under $A^{\star}y^{\star}=c$

where $(K+b)^{\star}$ is the negative polar of $K+b$

i.e.  $\left\{z^{\star}:<z^{\star},x>\geq\,0 \,\,\,\forall x\in K+b \right\}$.

I have assumed that$\,\, L$ is the whole space and certainly the intersection of the relative interiors is nonempty,(this is certainly satisfied). If $L$ is NOT the whole space the problem gets a lot more complicated!

Edit: It seems that it is not much more complicated than before! Let $L$ be a closed convex cone.

Define $P(x)=c^{T}x+\delta_{L}(x)$ and

$Q(Ax)=-\delta_{K+b}(Ax)\,\,$ as before.

The convex cojugate of $P$ is $P^{\star}(x^{\star})$=sup$\left\{x^{\star }x-c^{T}x-\delta_{L}(x) \right\}$ which is $\delta_{L_{0}}(x^{\star}-c)$=$-\delta_L^{\star}(c-x^{\star})$.

So the dual problem takes the form:

Maximize  $-\delta_{(K+b)^{\star}}(y^{\star})$+$\delta_{L^{\star}}(c-x^{\star})$,  under $x^{\star}=A^{\star}y^{\star}$

which gives

Maximize  $-\delta_{(K+b)^{\star}}(y^{\star})$+$\delta_{L^{\star}}(c-A^{\star}y^{\star})$

Comment: Could you provide an example of when $L$ is not the whole space and the problem becomes more complicated? Would the Lagrangian duality approach I outline, but with the introduction of another dual variable $\mu$ for $x\in L$ not work / become complicated?

Comment: ΟK! Shall we assume that L is also a closed convex cone or an affine set (a hyperplane)?

Comment: Personally I was thinking closed convex cone (though I'm curious about both now!)