# How is the dual problem for conic programs derived via Lagrangians?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems, conic-programming

I'm trying to get a better grip of conic programming and the relations between primal and dual problems.

Given a convex problem in standard form, *e.g.* $\min_x f(x)$ subject to $f_i(x)\le0$, one standard approach (discussed *e.g.* in these [pdf notes](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Esatishr/cs270/sp12/slides/lecture8/lecture8.outline.pdf)) is to introduce the Lagrangian function
$$L(x,\lambda) \equiv f(x) + \sum_i \lambda_i f_i(x), $$
and then argue that if $L(x,\lambda)\ge\alpha$ for all $x$, then the solution to the primal problem is at least $\alpha$.

Consider now a standard conic programming problem, in the form (using the notation from [these other pdf notes](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ewatrous/QIT-notes/QIT-notes.01.pdf)):
$$\max_x \{ \langle a,x\rangle, \,\, \phi(x)=b, \,\, x\in K \},$$
where $\phi$ is a linear function, and $K$ a closed convex cone. To argue that the dual problem leads a solution larger than the primal one, the argument they use is a bit different: they show that
$$\langle a,x\rangle \le \langle y,b\rangle$$
whenever $\phi^*(y)-b\in K^*$, where $\phi^*$ is the adjoint of $\phi$, and $K^*$ the dual cone of $K$.

I've read that duality in conic programming should also be derivable via the Lagrangian approach (it is mentioned, but not further elaborated, on top of page 7 in [these other pdf notes](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/%7Enemirovs/ICMNemirovski.pdf)). How would we actually do this, explicitly? I'm not quite seeing how defining a Lagrangian like $L(x,\lambda)=\langle a,x\rangle+\lambda^T (\phi(x)-b)$ will eventually lead me to the dual problem. Mostly because I'm not sure how to encode the $x\in K$ constraint in it.

---

A related question is *[How to derive the dual of a conic programming problem, $\min_{x\in L}\{c^T x: \,\, Ax-b\in K\}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4495329/173147)*

Answer (score 1):

The main idea is that we can use the relation $x\in K$ implicitly; we could penalize it directly in the Lagrangian, but we can also use the fact that $x\in K$ to derive a relation on other quantities.

Consider
\begin{align}
\begin{array}
&\nu (P) := & \max & \langle c, x\rangle \\
&\text{s.t.} & Ax = b\\
&& x\in K
\end{array}
\end{align}
for linear function $A$ (and adjoint $A^*$).
Then the Lagrangian can be formed by
\begin{align}
L(x;\lambda) &= \langle c,x \rangle + \langle \lambda, b-Ax\rangle = \langle c,x \rangle + \langle \lambda, b\rangle -\langle \lambda,Ax\rangle\\
&=\langle c - A^*\lambda ,x \rangle + \langle \lambda, b\rangle\\
\end{align}
and since $x\in K$, we can ensure that $L(x;\lambda) \geq \langle c, x\rangle$ as long as we require $c-A^*\lambda\in K^*$ (since for any $x\in K$ and $y\in K^*$, $\langle x,y \rangle\geq0$).

The dual can be derived as minimizing the upper bound $(b^\top \lambda)$ subject to the constraints that make the upper bound valid ($c-A^*\lambda\in K^*$):
\begin{align}
\nu(P) \leq \min_\lambda \{\langle b,\lambda\rangle : c - A^*\lambda \in K^*\}.
\end{align}

Comment: ah, so simple, but I think I see it now. So generalising to constraints $Ax-b\in L$ and $x\in K$ for some pair of closed convex cones, we'd write $\langle c,x\rangle=\langle c-A^T y,x\rangle+\langle y,Ax-b\rangle + \langle y,b\rangle$ which is lesser than $\langle y,b\rangle$ whenever $A^T y -c \in K^*$ and $-y\in L^*$. Brilliant. I wonder: can the same idea be applied if there is only *one* constraint, say, $x\in K$ for some cone $K$ (granted solution will be often unbounded in such cases, but still)